# 2 problems with VB Net's XMLWriter

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-serialization, xmlwriter

Im writing stuff to an XML file using VB .net´s XmlTextWriter

The code to start the xmlwriter is:

```
 Dim XMLobj As Xml.XmlTextWriter
 Dim enc As System.Text.Encoding
 enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
 XMLobj = New Xml.XmlTextWriter("C:\filename.xml", enc)
```

Is it possible to add param="on" to the first line of the XML file? So that it will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" param="on"?>
```

The next question might be a stupid one :) but I just can't figure it out.
I try to add a doctype to the XML file like:

```
<!DOCTYPE Test SYSTEM "test/my.dtd">
```

However when I try to set this up I get some errors.

```
XMLobj.WriteDocType("Test", null, "test/my.dtd", null)
```

The error I get is:

```
'null' is not declared. 'Null' constant is no longer supported; use 'System.DBNull' instead.
```

However when I try to replace null with System.DBNull I get the error:

```
'DBNull' is a type in 'System' and cannot be used as an expression.
```

The result of the doctype def should be like:

```
<!DOCTYPE Test SYSTEM "test/my.dtd">
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:**

What it looks like you're trying to do is append a ["processing instruction"](http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=pi.sql&id=18238) to your XML file. A processing instruction (PI) is a tag that encodes application-specific information, beginning with `"<?"` and ending with `"?>"`.

To add a PI to your XML file, you need to use the [`WriteProcessingInstruction` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.writeprocessinginstruction.aspx) of the `XmlTextWriter` class. There are two parts to every PI, a target and a value, and these are the two parameters accepted by the `WriteProcessingInstruction` method.

So, in your case, you would write the following code to append the processing instruction:

```
XMLobj.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1"" param=""on""")
```

which would produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" param="on"?>
```

**Question 2:**

The VB.NET equivalent of C#'s `null` is [`Nothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). This keyword either specifies the default value of a value type, or a null value of a reference type.

You should not use [`System.DBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) unless you're dealing with databases. `DBNull` represents an uninitialized variant or non-existent database column. It is *not* equivalent to `Nothing` or `null`. I agree that the first error message you get is confusing at best.

So, instead, the line to write the DocType to the XML file should be:

```
XMLobj.WriteDocType("Test",  Nothing, "test/my.dtd", Nothing)
```

which will produce:

```
<!DOCTYPE Test SYSTEM "test/my.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

I have answer about "null" - it's called "Nothing" in VB.net